# Functional Equation involving Golden Ratio

Tags: functions, functional-equations, golden-ratio

> Find all $h:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that
>   $$h(h(n)) + h(n+1) = n+2$$

I tried this, but wasn't able to make any progress after a while. So, in vain,
I looked at the solution. The solution basically obtained $h(1)=1$ and $h(2)=2$ after some casework, and then claimed that
$$h(n) = \lfloor n\alpha \rfloor -n + 1$$
(where $\alpha$ denotes the golden ratio)
without explaining at all why one would come at such a conclusion.
How did they jump to this conclusion?

(Source: Functional Equations: A Problem Solving Approach, Venkatachala.)